# Low Seg2Cat: Category Image filedir is not parsing

Tags: categories, low-seg2cat

I have an issue where it seems that my category images are not being parsed properly.

`{if segment_3_category_image}<img src="{segment_3_category_image}" alt="{segment_3_category_name}" class="fright" />{/if}`

is being rendered as:

`<img src="{filedir_7}apron150x150.gif" alt="Stories" class="fright">`

Obviously, it’s getting a value for the image, but the template is not parsing the `filedir` value. Is there something that might be missing? This is sitting inside of the following page embed around `line 22`.

```
{if segment_3 =="video-tv" OR segment_3 == "radio-podcasts"}
        <div id="banner">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="shows" limit="1" disable="pagination|member_data"}
            <div class="vid-slide">
                <a href="{title_permalink='shows/'}">
                {if show_screenshot}<img src="{show_screenshot}" width="477" height="260" alt="{title}" />
                {if:elseif show_screenshot == "" AND segment_3 == "video-tv"}<img src="/assets/images/show/show_generic.jpg" width="477" height="260" alt="{title}" />
                {if:elseif show_screenshot == "" AND segment_3 == "radio-podcasts"}<img src="/assets/images/show/radio_generic.jpg" width="477" height="260" alt="{title}" />{/if}</a>
                <div class="blurb">
                    <h1>{title}</h1>
                    <p>{show_intro}</p>
                    {if segment_3 == "video-tv"}<p class="button"><a href="{title_permalink='shows/'}">Watch Now</a></p>{/if}
                    {if segment_3 == "radio-podcasts"}<p class="button"><a href="{title_permalink='shows/'}">Listen Now</a></p>{/if}
                </div>
            </div>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        </div>
{/if}       
        <section id="main">
<h1>{segment_3_category_name}</h1>
<div class="divide">
{if segment_3_category_image}<img src="{segment_3_category_image}" alt="{segment_3_category_name}" class="fright" />{/if}

{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_shows_{segment_3}_main"}

<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="shows" disable="member_data" paginate="bottom" limit="12"}
<li><h2><a href="{title_permalink='shows/'}">{title}</a></h2>
<p>{show_intro}</p></li>
{paginate}
<li><p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p></li>
{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
</div>
        </section>

        <aside id="sidebar">
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_shows_{segment_3}_sidebar"}<hr/>
{if segment_3 == "video-tv"}{exp:low_variables:parse var="tg_sponsors"}{/if}
{gv_subscribe}
<br/>
{gv_support-efforts}
        </aside>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's looking like Low Seg2Cat. Make sure you're on the latest version and the Parse File Paths is turned on in the [settings](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs#settings).

Comment: Looks like I hadn't set Parse File Paths! Thanks!